# Books on prime gaps?

Tags: reference-request

I want to have a book on prime gaps, which includes both the theory of prime gaps and all the results obtained.

The conditions may be harsh, but I hope I can have some recommendations that fit at least one of the two conditions.

Comment: Large gaps or small. But I cannot think of any books. Have you looked at http://www.primegaps.com/links/ ? The Wikipedia entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap has some reasonable references.

Comment: @almagest: Thanks very much. I have checked the relevant materials, but what I found are isolated short pieces. So I want to have an organized, systematic book on this subject of study.

Comment: This only recently became a hot research area. I don't think anyone has had time to write books yet!

Comment: @almagest: Thanks. Yes, because of Zhang's epoch-making result. But this field can be dated back to long long ago; it is weird that no number theorist writes up a specialized pamphlet on this topic :)

Comment: Not really. For a long time, it did not have many results of any significance. But these things are driven by fashion.

Comment: Andrew Granville has an overview paper on this [here](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/CEBBrochureFinal.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Paulo Ribenboim](https://www.google.it/search?q=Paulo+Ribenboim&btnG=Cerca+nei+libri&tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=en&gws_rd=cr&ei=B7IpVYV-gv9o7qqBwA4) has written (three?) books about primes that include topics about prime gaps.